# Using 「という」to describe things

Tags: grammar, particle-こと

I was learning about how we can use 「という」to describe things and I saw the following example:

- 日本人{にほんじん}はお酒{さけ}に弱{よわ}い**という**のは本当{ほんとう}？

And my question is, what is the use of 「という」when used to describe this type of things? Wouldn't this phrase be equal to: 日本人{にほんじん}はお酒{さけ}に弱{よわ}い**こと**は本当{ほんとう}？ If so whats the benefit of using 「という」? I also saw the following example:

- リブート**という**のは、パソコンを再起動{さいきどう}する**という**ことです。

And in this phrase, in the end, 「という」 is used with 「こと」. why is 「こと」there? Wouldn't the sentence be correct like this: リブート**という**のは、パソコンを再起動{さいきどう}する**という**です.?

Answer (score 2):

One important note is that while you can use という to name things (e.g.,「ドラえもん」**という**漫画【まんが】を見【み】る。),  you can also use it to literally mean that something is said:

- その漫画【まんが】が好【す】きじゃない**というのは**本当【ほんとう】じゃないです。

In the phrase というの, there are three components. The particle と here marks a quotation; the verb 言【い】う, often just written in kana, means "to say"; and the particle の nominalizes a preceding verb. (In other words, it turns a verb into a gerund.) So the above sentence would translate as "To say that I don't like that manga would not be true."

You can also define things using というのは, as in your second example, which can be translated as "To 'reboot' is to restart a computer".

Incidentally, ということです is also a set phrase in some situations. It's a bit like the phrase "as it's said"; you can usually replace it with です, but it gives a softer tone to whatever you're saying. (Weblio translates it as "The thing is, ...") It can also [mark something one has heard](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A0-to-iu-koto-da-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A0-to-no-koto-da-meaning/). Similarly, ということで can be translated as "that is to say" or "in other words".